# Implementation of the command cd (cd -L) in C without exec functions

Tags: c, symlink, chdir

I'm trying to code the command cd in C without using the exec functions, I already did the cd -P version but I can't seem to find a way to do cd (cd -L) because the function chdir resolves the symlinks so my cd -L acts like cd -P.

For cd -P I did one function which takes the path we want to get to as a parameter and I have a variable old_pwd that acts like $OLDPWD in my file (I use getenv("PWD") to initialize it), if the parameter is empty I just use chdir on $HOME, if the parameter is "-" I use chdir on the variable old_pwd and finally if its a path I use chdir on that path.
If you have an idea on how to change the current directory without resolving any symlink I will be very grateful !

Comment: `cd` can't be implemented as a **program**, only as a command within some other program (like the shell).  What's the context here?

Comment: @DavisHerring, I take the OP to be talking about implementing `cd` in the context of a custom shell.  Nevertheless, POSIX does require that `cd`, as a standard utility and not a "special built-in" one, be available as a command that can be accessed via the `exec` family of functions.  Interestingly enough, however, although both my Linux workstation and my Mac indeed do provide such an external `cd` command, their `/bin/cd` and `/usr/bin/cd`, respectively, do not produce behavior consistent with the POSIX specs.

Comment: I am trying to make my own shell in C, I am making different files for the commands that I want to implement and right now I'm focusing on `cd` using `chdir`.
The problem I was trying to explain is that I do not want to follow any symbolic link in the path but since `chdir` resolves them I can't figure a solution.
I tried to understand the algorithm gave by @JohnBollinger but I am not sure I truly understood it and if the example I gave bellow was wrong.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Interesting: some of my systems don't have any `cd` on `PATH`, and the ones that do have it as a shell script!  Nor do I [see](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) the requirement that it be a program.  In any case, you were right about the context here.

Comment: @DavisHerring, it is a general requirement of *all* standard POSIX utilities (which `cd` is) other than special built-in utilities (which `cd` is not) that they be available in a form that can be exercised via the `exec` family of functions.  This is in [section 1.6 of the *Shell and Utilities* chapter of POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIX [Path resolution](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) works through a path stepwise, from beginning to end, resolving symlinks as it goes.  This is how POSIX `chdir()` interprets paths, and it is consistent with the behavior of `cd -P`.

[`cd -L`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) requires different behavior: that steps of the form `..` be interpreted relative to the other literal steps in the given path, regardless of whether any steps designate symbolic links.  That behavior differs from `chdir()`'s, so you have to implement it yourself.  This is largely a matter of parsing and processing appearances of `.` and `..` in the path before handing off the result  to `chdir()`.

The POSIX specs for `cd`, linked above, provide a detailed algorithm for how `cd -L` should perform the needed path manipulations.  As such, I have removed the algorithm I presented in an earlier version of this answer, and replaced the notes regarding it with notes pertaining to the official POSIX specifications.

Notes:

1. POSIX defines an obscure environment variable `CDPATH` and some directory-search semantics for `cd` associated with that.  Details are in the linked specs.  If you're going for full POSIX semantics then you'll need to handle that; otherwise, I doubt whether very many people would notice the absence of that feature.
2. The effect of `-P` is to pass the specified path to `chdir()` as-is, provided that any target path is in fact specified, or to pass the value of `$HOME` to `chdir()` if no path is otherwise specified.
3. When `-L` is in effect, relative paths are interpreted with respect to the current value of `$PWD`.  Processing of leading `..` path steps takes that into account.
4. POSIX specifies that `..` processing causes `cd` to fail with an error if the leading path preceding the `..`, interpreted according to the standard path-resolution rule (including symlink traversal), does not designate a directory.  That is,

   - `dir1/dir2/..` and `dir1/symlink-to-dir3/..` are both ok, and both are equivalent to `dir1`, but
   - `dir1/regular-file/..`, `dir1/not-a-filename/..`, and similar are erroneous.
5. The `-L` behavior is the default if neither `-P` nor `-L` is given.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply I just wanted to get some clarifications :
If I have directories like this : `test/dir1/dir2/dir3` and `test/dir4` with `test/dir4 -> test/dir1/dir2/dir3` a symbolic link
If I'm in `dir4` and I want to get to `test` and not `dir2` by using `cd ..` the path will not change with the algorithm you gave but if I use `chdir` on `..` it will still get me to `dir2` and not `test` because it will follow the symbolic link in `dir4`
So should `..` change with this algorithm ?

Comment: @Chae, I have performed a major revision of this answer.  It now refers you to the official POSIX specifications for `cd`, which include their own algorithm for how `cd -L` must mangle paths.  This does take the shell's idea of the path to the current working directory (from `$PWD`) into account when `-P` is not in effect.